# Flexbox footer won't evenly space

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, responsive

)

I'm a super novice coder just trying to make a responsive site for my music.  I have managed to get a basic template together, but my footer isn't working how I'd hoped.
I've put 4 image/ a tags in to link to social sites in my footer but I can't get them to space evenly using flexbox.

I've tried every combination of alignment (both items and contents), justify (both items and contents), all flex display combinations.  They aren't moving. They are crunched together in the center of the footer and won't budge.  Any help would be appreciated!

here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Science From SVN</title>
</head>

<div class="container">
<body>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/_IMAGES/logo/SCIENCE FROM SVN WHITE.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="menu-toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <main>
        <!-- Your main content goes here -->
        <p>This is the main content of your page.</p>
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="social_links">
            <a href="#"><img src="/_IMAGES/social/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="/_IMAGES/social/Instagram.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="/_IMAGES/social/Youtube.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="/_IMAGES/social/purchase.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </footer>    

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS

```
html {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Ensure container takes at least the full height of the viewport */

}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient( to left top, blue, black);
}

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* background-color: #333; */
    background-color: #242424;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: .5px solid white;
}

.nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-list li {
    margin-right: 20px;

}

.nav-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.bar {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;   
}

.logo img {
    max-height: 7.5vh;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

main {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    background-color: #242424;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    border-top: .5px solid white;
}

footer img {
    width: 2.5rem; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    justify-content: sp
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
 {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-list {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 77px;
        left: 0;
        background:#242424;
        padding: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }

    .nav-list.show {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav-list li {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .menu-toggle.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
    }

    .menu-toggle.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .menu-toggle.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-15px, -15px);
    }

    .bar {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;   
    }

    .logo img {  
    max-height: 9vh;
    height: 10vh;
    padding-left: .1rem;
    }

}
```

THANK YOU!  Still learning but I'm having fun

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Small changes make a big difference.  Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Below will fix your footer.

```
footer {
    background-color: #242424;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    border-top: .5px solid white;
}

.social_links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

footer img {
    width: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```